# Enum Attribute order changing after first access

Tags: c#, enums

We have the following enum:

```
public enum TrafficLight
    {
        [Description("../../images/dot-red.png")]
        [AwesomeIcon("<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-red'></i>")]
        Red = 0,
        [Description("../../images/dot-yellow.png")]
        [AwesomeIcon("<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-yellow'></i>")]
        Yellow = 1,
        [Description("../../images/dot-green.png")]
        [AwesomeIcon("<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-green'></i>")]
        Green = 2,
        [Description("../../images/dot-gold.png")]
        [AwesomeIcon("<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-gold'></i>")]
        Gold = 3,
        [Description("../../images/dot-grey.png")]
        [AwesomeIcon("<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-grey'></i>")]
        Grey = 99
    }
```

`AwesomeIcon` inherits from the `DescriptionAttribute` class:

```
 public class AwesomeIcon : DescriptionAttribute
    {
        public AwesomeIcon(string icon)
            : base(icon)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem is when the Enum description is accessed more than once, the order of the attributes changes. For example, we're getting the description like so:

```
 public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value, int index = 0)
        {
            var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

            var attributes =
                fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];

            if(attributes == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if (attributes.Any() && index <= attributes.Length)
            {
                return attributes[index].Description;
            }   

            return value.ToString();
        }
```

**First Access**

```
GetEnumDescription(TrafficLight.Red);
//Returns "../../images/dot-red.png" as expected.
//Debug GetEnumDescription attributes variable
[0]Description
[1]AwesomeIcon
```

**Second Access**

```
GetEnumDescription(TrafficLight.Yellow);
//Returns "<i class='fa fa-lg fa-circle v4-yellow'></i>" 
// which is the value of AwesomeIcon.
//Debug GetEnumDescription attributes variable
[0]AwesomeIcon
[1]Description
```

Every access after the order remains `AwesomeIcon`, then `Description`.

The problem is that AwesomeIcon inherits from Description and it's getting picked up. If the order remains the same in the array it wouldn't be a problem, I can reference it by index.

I've not experienced this before, any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to see if [GetCustomAttributes preserve order](https://www.bing.com/search?q=GetCustomAttributes%20preserve%20order) like  discussed in this answer:  [Does GetCustomAttributes() preserve the attribute order in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480007/does-getcustomattributes-preserve-the-attribute-order-in-net)?

Comment: Don't have `AwesomeIconAttribute` inherit from `DescriptionAttriute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure you have a `DescriptionAttribute` (even if it's inherited), with something like:

```
var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);
var myDescriptionAttribute = 
      attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
```

And forget about indices. Attributes are not guaranteed an order so an index is rather useless.

By using `x => x.GetType() == typeof(DescriptionAttribute)` you get an exact type match.

I've made a fiddle demonstrating two possible methods (using generics or just finding the `DescriptionAttribute`): https://dotnetfiddle.net/StUvqf

But basically:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);
    var theDescriptionAttribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof (DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
    if (theDescriptionAttribute == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return theDescriptionAttribute.Description;
}
```

or:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription<T>(Enum value)
    where T : DescriptionAttribute
{
    var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (T), false);
    var theDescriptionAttribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof (T)) as T;
    if (theDescriptionAttribute == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return theDescriptionAttribute.Description;
}
```

Of course might need some more `null` checkings, but I'll leave that to you

As an extra hint, `FieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes` never returns null (it may return an empty array, but not null), so you could just remove that null check :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you can sort the attributes by Names, this will help you getting them in the same order every time.

```
var attributes =
         fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false) as object[];

if(attributes.Any())
  {
   // Ascending order
   Array.Sort(attributes, (x, y) => 
    String.Compare(x.GetType().Name, y.GetType().Name)); 
  }
```

**And fix a bug in `GetEnumDescription(Enum value, int index = 0)`:**

```
if (attributes.Any() && index <= attributes.Length)
```

should be

```
if (attributes.Any() && index < attributes.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and the bug fix! I've decided it was better to not rely on the order and get it explicitly by DescriptionAttribute.

Comment: Yup that should be the approach. Quick fixes are not for long term they become painful sooner or later.